# Usage of "expect to" and "expectation to/of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

I've written:

> I expect to see you on Monday. I'm
>   counting the days.

To improve it, I've changed it in:

> With the expectation to see you on
>   Monday, I'm counting the days.

A friend told me: No! You should write the following.

> With the expectation **of seeing** you
>   on Monday, I'm counting the
>   days.

Who's the smart one? My friend or me? Is there a general rule to apply here? Like with *expect/expectation*, but also for *willing/wish*, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the properties of individual words in a language - and often one of the hardest for foreigners to learn - is what linguists call their "subcategorization frame" : the particular kinds of word and phrase that they require, or allow, to follow them in a sentence.

Rhodri's answer is generally correct: "expect" requires a direct object, which may be of various types including a "that" clause ("I expect that he will come", and an infinitive clause ("I expect to win"). 
But "expectation" has different requirements: it may take a direct object only if that is a "that" clause ("His expectation that I would come"; any other object must be expressed in a PP (prepositional phrase) introduced by "of": "my expectation of winning").

The bit I disagree with in Rhodri's answer is the implication that *because it is a noun*, "expectation" cannot take a direct infinitive. This is not so: "expectation" does not take an infinitive, but "ability" can: ("His ability to climb came in useful").

Comment: So you are saying that `expectation to see` is grammatically wrong?

Comment: It's a matter of taste (or theoretical perspective) whether you regard subcategorisation errors as errors of grammar or not. (Traditional grammar didn't even notice there was such a concept). No native speaker would say "expectation to see" as far as I know, so I guess if pushed I would say yes, it's ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is right that "expectation of seeing" is preferred to "expectation to see" (that is, it sounds more natural).

Still, I think you could say it still another way:

> Expecting to see you on Monday, I'm counting the days.

Answer (score 1):

In "I expect to see you," *to* is introducing the [infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive) "to see".  It happens to be the way that the verb *expect* works that it takes an infinitive.

When you rearrange the sentence to start "With the expectation...", *expectation* is a noun.  It doesn't get to take an infinitive, so that rule doesn't apply.  English then heads off into a maze of special cases about what words to use when, or indeed whether to use an intervening particle at all.  In this case, we would say:

> With the expectation *of* seeing you...
>
> With the expectation *that* I will see you...

**Edit:** I originally said that "expectation" didn't take an infinitive *because it wasn't a verb.*  As Colin points out, I was completely wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Your original sentence is the best of the alternatives presented.

Perhaps better still, though, is simply to elide (leave out) "to see".

> I expect you on Monday.  I'm counting
>   the days.