# "Expectations from" vs "Expectations for"

Tags: word-choice

> I have good expectations **from** traveling.
>
> I have good expectations **for** traveling.

Which one is correct? [From this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335265/expectations-of-vs-expectations-for), it seems that "expectations for" is correct because we are talking about an "anticipated result in store with the future." However, "expectations from" sounds natural to me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about past and future tense.

> I have good expectations **from** traveling.

**From** infers that the speaker is drawing from experiences of travelling in the past on which they base their ideas (expectations) of a future journey.

> I have good expectations **for** traveling.

The speaker has ideas **for** a future journey. There is no allusion of where they construct their expectations **from**.

Comment: I use the British spelling (double l) but the OP has used the correct *American* spelling with one l. See for example [double-l-spelling-rule](https://howtospell.co.uk/double-l-spelling-rule)

Comment: Cheers, pardon me. Gah! Can I use the "I'm new to the internet" excuse today :)

Hahaha!

Answer (score 1):

"Expectations from" is not a natural construction in this context.

> ### "[From](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/from)"
>
> 3 Indicating the source or provenance of someone or something.
>
> - *‘I'm from Hackney’*
> - *‘she rang him from the hotel’*
> - *‘she demanded the keys from her husband’*

In this context, "from" would suggest that the act of travelling is the source of or has *produced* the good expectations.

As you note, an "expectation" relates to a future event, so the first sentence would only make sense if the travelling has already occurred and the expectations therefore relate to something else that's going to happen.

But this is not what you mean, since the alternative "good expectations for travelling" suggests that the travelling has not yet happened and the expectations relate to the (future) act of travelling itself.